# Infinite scrolling in Rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, infinite-scroll

I'm using the [pageless plugin](https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless/blob/master/lib/jquery.pageless.js) for my infinte scrolling.

In the usage he has mention as:

```
$('#results').pageless({ 
    totalPages: 10,
    url: '/articles/',
    loaderMsg: 'Loading more results'
});
```

What should I write in place of `"#results"`? I'm new to rails so I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Give the id of the element inside which your first page is loaded. Pagination will do the magic and append the rest of your contents to the same div

Answer (score 0):

That's ok.

You only have to place a `div` in your **html** with the `id` `results`

```
<div id=results></div>
```

The plugin will do the rest.